# Mining cycles from graphs

Tags: data-mining, graph-theory

Suppose $T$ is a set of transactions containing some paths taken from a set of undirected graphs $G$ whose nodes are all taken from the same finite alphabet $A$. I would now like to extract all frequent cycles (strongly connected components) from $T$ by using the Apriori algorithm.

The idea is that since the Apriori is anti-monotone in the support parameter (for the item $(abc)$ to be frequent, all subsets $(ab)$, $(ac)$, $(bc)$ etc must also be frequent), it is sufficient to just extract all rules of length $2$, ie. $a\to b$, $b\to c$ etc. Returning to the graph representation, we do not need to extract paths like $a\to b \to c \to d$, because they can all be described as a set of paths of length $2$.

Am I correct in saying that by combining all such rules/paths of length $2$ from $T$ into a new directed graph $G'$, the strongly connected components can be extracted?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I correct in saying that by combining all such rules/paths of length 2 from T into a new directed graph G′, the strongly connected components can be extracted?

I don't have a citation for you, but I think you've essentially just restated the Apriori algorithm in graph notation (I'm accustomed to a set notation description), so I believe your reasoning is correct.